# How to create thumbnail and store it in another folder using CI3.1.2?

Tags: codeigniter

I am using CI version 3.1.2 to process an image and using Windows 8. My problem is every time i process an image and trying to create a thumbnail, i am countering a message **"Unable to save the image. Please make sure the image and file directory are writable"**. This is occurred when trying to save the copy of thumbnail into different location. Here are my codes processing the image:

```
$this->original_path = realpath(APPPATH.'../assets/galery/full');

// Uploading image
$config = [
  'allowed_types'   => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
  'upload_path'     => $this->original_path,
  'max_size'        => 2048,
  'maintain_ratio'  => true,
  'file_name'       => 'img_'.strtotime(date('d-m-y-H-i-s')), // miss type
  'overwrite'       => true,
  'remove_spaces'   => true
];
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->do_upload('galery');
$file_name = $this->upload->file_name;

// Processing image, success processing image
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$img = [
  'image_library'   => 'gd2',
  'source_image'    => $this->original_path.'/'.$file_name,
  'maintain_ratio'  => true,
  'width'           => 600
];
$this->image_lib->initialize($img);
$this->image_lib->resize();

// This is fail, with message "Unable to save the image... using(var_dump())
$thumb = [
  'source_image'    => $this->original_path.'/'.$file_name,
  'new_image'       => '/assets/galery/small',
  'maintain_ratio'  => true,
  'width'           => 200
];

$this->image_lib->initialize($thumb);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

I've tried different config, like using `realpath(APPPATH.'../assets/galery/small')`, but still no luck. It is success, by the way, when create config using `'create_thumb'`.
But my purpose is, saving that thumbnail in another folder. How can i achieve that?

**UPDATE**

This change seem to work well. I change `realpath(APPPATH.'../assets/galery/full')` to `realpath(APPPATH.'../assets/galery')` and make several change in:

```
...
'upload_path' => $this->original_path.'/full'
...
'source_image' => $this->original_path.'/full/'.$file_name
...
'new_image' => $this->original_path.'/small/thumb_'.$file_name
```

Until now i'm still trying to make my code simple and put it in MY_Model. Thanks for all comment(s). If some one may have better solution, it would be nice to share here.

Comment: You should try with `FCPATH` instead of `$this->original_path`

Comment: Have you checked 777 permisions for /assets/galery/small folder?

Comment: @Karlis i am using Windows, and yes i set all folder permission to full. I try several options that seem running well. See my update.

Comment: @Mayank I will try your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @MSI I hope it working